# Android: Fragment takes up entire screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a `<fragment>`for Map Activity in my Android app. This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="481dp" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:src="@drawable/tick"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

However, when the app is running, it is consuming the entire screen and the entire screen shows the map and squeezed button is displayed.

[image: This is how it is displayed]

However when I'm designing the app in the layout phase, it shows proper formatting.

[image: Proper Format]

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I see a squeezed green button in the emulator photo

Comment: Yup I don't want it squeezed. How to fix the resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the floating button for better and modern Material implementation, which removes all kinds of issues.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_request"
            android:text="Request Pickup"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/map_button">

        </Button>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            app:backgroundTint="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end"/>

    </fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <fragment
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:layout_below="@+id/map" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
            android:src="@drawable/tick" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

make your layout LinearLayout and assign weights to it. Something like this.

```
 <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_weight="0.8"
          >
       <Fragment>
       </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_weight="0.2"
     >
    <Button></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So set fragment height to wrap_content, set align parent top and match the bottom of the fragment with the top of the imageview useing `android:layout_above`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:src="@drawable/tick"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Update:

Crash Log:

`08-18 18:26:40.314    3107-3107/abhishekdey.ecosquare D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
08-18 18:26:40.363    3107-3107/abhishekdey.ecosquare E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: abhishekdey.ecosquare, PID: 3107
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1701)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:381)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:389)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)`

UPDATE:
This should work

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

            <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="@drawable/round" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/tick"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `Process: abhishekdey.ecosquare, PID: 3107
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1701)`

Comment: Try to replace `android:layout_below="@+id/map"` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` . I suggest yu to use a RelativeLayout to wrap the ImageView and Button.